# How to start subsequent shells as root?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, root, autologin

I run my local testing server inside a VM. I often have to open up multiple windows in it, and all have to be logged in root. Usually this is accomplished by writing `su` on every tab, a total of 7-8 times.

Is there a way that I have to enter the root password only once, and the next terminal tab/window that I open has be logged in as root? Sort of like it maintains the current working directory?

Answer (score 2):

You'd simply open a terminal emulator as root.

```
su -l -c gnome-terminal
```

This will launch the "gnome-terminal" as root. This way, any tab in that terminal emulator will be a root one.

`sudo -b gnome-terminal` could work better but I do not have an ubuntu to check if it works out of the box.

Answer (score 2):

### In a Graphical Session

When you're logged in graphically, you can run your graphical terminal emulator app as `root`, as others have said. The best way to do this is typically with [`gksu` or `gksudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/gksu.1.html), as this automatically handles changing `HOME` to `/root` and (less importantly) uses a temporary `.Xauthority` file ([source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Graphical_sudo)). `gksu` is a frontend for both `su` and `sudo` and on most OSes will be configured to use whichever one is the more standard way for administrators to run programs as `root`. (Or you can specify which one with `gksu --su-mode` and `gksu --sudo-mode`, the latter of which is always equivalent to running `gksudo` without either flag.)

#### GNOME

`gksu gnome-terminal` or `gksudo gnome-terminal`

#### KDE (uses [`kdesu`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/en/man1/kdesu.1.html) or [`kdesudo`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/kdesudo.1.html) instead)

`kdesu gnome-terminal` or `kdesudo gnome-terminal`

- Please note that `kdesu` is usually only present and in the `PATH` on systems where `su` is a supported way to run programs as `root`. That is not the case on some GNU/Linux OSes, such as Ubuntu.

#### Xfce

`gksu xfce4-terminal` or `gksudo xfce4-terminal`

#### LXDE

`gksu lxterminal` or `gksudo lxterminal`

*As [andcoz](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61605/11938) and [aurelien lambrosse](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/61604/11938) have said, running your graphical terminal emulator as `root` makes all the shells that come up in its tabs (and new windows, if created from the `root` terminal's menus) run as `root`.*

### In a Text-Based Session

If you don't have the ability to run GUI programs ([virtual console](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_console) login, `ssh` login without `-X`, or you just don't want to), the above solution won't work for you. In that case, you might consider using a screen manager that lets you control multiple terminals in one. This effectively achieves the same goal as a `root`-owned GUI terminal with multiple tabs...just without the GUI.

[`screen`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/screen.1.html) is the most common screen manager. You can [use these commands](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Getting-Started) to control it once it's running.

Or use [`byobu`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/byobu.1.html), a handy wrapper for screen. `byobu` is often not provided on non-Ubuntu systems (though it can be installed on them). But you indicated you're running [ubuntu](/questions/tagged/ubuntu), so you should be able to use it.

[image: A just-launched byobu screen showing a shell and various information in the last two lines.]
<sup>**`byobu` running on Ubuntu 11.10. Information about the current "window" and the system are shown at the bottom.**</sup>

In `byobu` it's very easy to create new "windows" and to switch between them. <kbd>F2</kbd> makes one, <kbd>F3</kbd> switches backward, <kbd>F4</kbd> switches forward, and <kbd>F9</kbd> brings up the interactive main menu.

There are more default `byobu` keybindings. Here they are:

> ```
> F2    Create a new window    |  F7    Scrollback and search
> F3    Go to the prev window  |  F8    Rename a window
> F4    Go to the next window  |  F9    Configuration
> F5    Reload profile         |  F12   Screen escape sequence
> F6    Detach from session    |  'man byobu'  - byobu's help
> 'byobu'  - reattach session  |  'man screen' - screen's help
> ```

**Source**: `byobu` built-in help, accessible in the <kbd>F9</kbd> configuration menu

See also the documentation on the Ubuntu website for [Screen (in the community wiki)](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen) and [Byobu (in the Server Guide)](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.10/serverguide/byobu.html).

Answer (score 0):

you can launch, for example, a gnome-terminal instance as root :

```
$ sudo gnome-terminal
```

Then all tabs in this gnome-terminal instance will be open as root

Comment: This works. However I have to ask two things: 
1) Why can't I do gnone-terminal while logged in as root? This is what I am getting `** (gnome-terminal:2875): WARNING **: Failed to connect to the session manager: None of the authentication protocols specified are supported

g_dbus_connection_real_closed: Remote peer vanished with error: Underlying GIOStream returned 0 bytes on an async read (g-io-error-quark, 0). Exiting.
Terminated
`

Comment: @SaadRehmanShah If it's a non-graphical `root` login, you cannot run graphical programs (without configuring an X display). If it's a graphical `root` login, not much is guaranteed to work properly on most current Unix-like systems--you're not supposed to log in graphically as `root`, programs are not tested under these circumstances, and lots of stuff won't work.